# Where do I obtain the boundary for an address via OSM?

Tags: openstreetmap

[image]
The boundary around the address shown in red in the [OSM GUI](https://www.openstreetmap.org/), It does not return when querying, and in the download XML the "GeoJson" of this polygon does not show... is it possible to obtain this boundary via the API?
I'm not sure how it's being generated on the backend.

Comment: Note that addresses can both be defined as polygons and nodes in OSM! If you want to make sure to get all addresses, you have to download and process both polygons and nodes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the Nominatim API to geocode and return the polygon for the building outline `&polygon_geojson=1`

```
https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search/%224315,%20E%20Street%20Southeast,%20Washington%20DC?format=geojson&addressdetails=1&limit=1&polygon_geojson=1
```

This can be added to a GIS (QGIS used here) to read the GeoJSON file.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. is this 'polygon' to physical address available in the  OSM data dump download? or  Nominatim 3.5.0 server(with OSM Data)

Comment: http://download.geofabrik.de/north-america/us/district-of-columbia.html has shapefiles with buildings within the zip files

Comment: It is part of OSM, see https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/55388907.